# Is it possible to search microsoft.maps.mapcontrol?

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

I'm using Silverlight to extend an existing application that uses maps as referenced above.

The client wants to add a search function so that they can search for 'London' for example.

I can't find any answers ? Is microsoft.maps.mapcontrol different to Bing maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Bing Maps REST Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

You can find information on how to use the REST services in .NET here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

You can also find some tips and tricks about using the REST services here: http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-tricks/

Comment: Thanks. I had found it in the meantime but your answer is correct. The REST services are better also as they support https and avoid problems with the SOAP services over http being hosted in an https site. Thanks again though.